# No render output... why?

Tags: rendering

My rendering has no output, and I'm not sure why.

Here is the blend file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nHG4czlHThpvDe4Zoi6kiDGLi3wHkhDw/view

And pictures of the output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y16f5.jpg

Comment: Disabling the sequencer seems to fix it... not sure why - https://imgur.com/vCaM1NC

Comment: Oh, OK, you got it yourself. I did not see the comment when posting the answer. You should generally post it as an answer even if it's to your own question if you find a solution...

Answer (score 3):

It seems the output is there. It is black. It comes from your sequencer where there is a PNG file.. You need to disable sequencer or delete the strip with the PNG file.

[image]

It does not seem you have any lights in the scene as well.